# Multiple HTTP requests firing when using jquery modal from Backbone.js View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have simple Backbone.js App. I want to call jQuery modal plugin, when clicking a button in View. Definition of Modals structure (html) is outside of View's definition. What is proper way to use jquery with Backbone.js ?

```
   App.Views.Objava = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName :"div",
        className: "objava-single",


    initialize: function() {
     this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
         this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },


   events: 
    {
      'click #delete-objava': 'izbrisiObjavu',

    },

    remove: function() {
      this.$el.remove();
    },

    izbrisiObjavu: function(event)
        {

         var model = this.model;

         $(".modal-obrisi").modal();

         $(".dugme-obrisi").on("click", function(){

          model.destroy(); 

          $(".modal-obrisi").modal("hide");


         });

     }
 });
```

This type of code is causes problems, especially this part of caching view's model.

```
var model = this.model;
```

This part is somehow, on second deletion, creating multiple HTTP `DELETE` requests.

**EDIT**

[image: Problem image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing two requests going out when you delete your second post because the first `$(".modal-obrisi").on` has not been un-bound. So, if you try to delete a 3rd model, it will fire 3 requests, and so on.

To fix this, you should unbind by calling `.off`.

```
$(".dugme-obrisi").on("click", function(){
    model.destroy(); 
    $(".modal-obrisi").off().modal("hide");
});
```

Calling `.off()` without any arguments will turn off all event listeners for that element. If you want finer control, pass more filter arguments to it.

**OLD ANSWER**

Backbone is inherently meant to be non-prescriptive, so there is no particular "right way" to do things.

But I can recommend a couple of options from which you can pick whichever works best for your particular application:

**Option 1:** Pass the modal selector as an option to the view and use the selector to instantiate the modal.

```
// Parent
var view  = new App.Views.Objava({ modalSelector: ".dugme-obrisi" });
...

// View
App.Views.Objava = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    izbrisiObjavu: function(event) {
        $(this.options.modalSelector).modal();
    }
});
```

**Option 2:** Pass a callback to the view and let the parent handle the click event.

```
// Parent
var view  = new App.Views.Objava({ 
    callback: function() {
        $(".modal-obrisi").modal();
    } 
});
...

// View
App.Views.Objava = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    izbrisiObjavu: function(event) {
        if(this.options.callback) this.options.callback();
    }
});
```

**Option 3:** Make the modal it's own Backbone view.

```
// View
App.Views.Objava = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    izbrisiObjavu: function(event) {
        var modalView = new App.Views.ObjavaModal();
        this.$el.append(modalView.el);
        modalView.render();
    }
});

// Modal view
App.Views.ObjavaModal = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        // Render the modal content here
        ...

        // Make this view a modal
        this.$el.modal();
    }
});
```

I'm sure there are many more ways, but these are just a few.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, my problem remain's same. Maybe I didn't expalained it so good. When I try to secound time delete view from modal confirmation button, backbone sends two request. One for previous delete, one for current deleting procces. Image in EDIT.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah, I didn't understand your question. The multiple requests is because you're calling `.on` on the model twice. You have to call `.off` after you're done, or `destroy` the modal instead of `hide`.